# Обновление скрипта и запись рандомных чисел

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, случайные-числа

Есть скрипт на PROGRESS BAR в виде уровня воды в емкости .Как туда забивать рандомные числа и скрипт сам обновлялся ? 
[image]
JS

```
$(function () {
atualizaProgresso = function () {
    var percent = $('input[type=number]').val();
    var atual = $('#barra-progresso .concluido').data('p');
    percent = percent > 100 ? 100 : percent;
    mudaNumero(atual, percent);
    $('#barra-progresso .concluido').animate({
        height: percent + '%'
    }, {
        duration: 300,
        easing: "swing"
    });
    $('#barra-progresso .concluido').data('p', percent);
};
$('button').click(atualizaProgresso);
$('#barra-progresso .concluido').data('p', 0);
atualizaProgresso();
});


 function mudaNumero(de, para) {
if (typeof timer1 == "number") {
    clearInterval(timer1);
}

decimo = (para - de) / 10;
para = parseInt(para, 10);
de = parseInt(de, 10);

vezes = 1;
timer1 = window.setInterval(function () {
    if (vezes == 10) {
        clearInterval(timer1);
    }
    de = de + parseFloat(decimo, 10);
    $('#barra-progresso .percentual .numero').html(Math.round(de));
    vezes++;
    }, 30);
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
    var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
    $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
     });
```

Comment: Есть какие-то варианты или нет?